I get "timeout-or-duplicate" error using Recaptcha V3 and success status as false
This is the code and its causing issue but I am not sure how , its failing the response. Can someone guide me whats wrong here.
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onloadCallback&render=${recaptchaConfig.siteKey}"></script>
<script>
function onloadCallback() {
$("#submitID").prop('disabled',true);
grecaptcha.ready(function() {
var sitekey = document.getElementById('sitekey').value;
grecaptcha.execute(sitekey, {action: 'loginForm'}).then(function(token) {

var secret_Key="";

    $.ajax({
      type:'post',
      url: '/services/abcd/ajax/servletRecaptcha',
      data:{response: token,sk:secret_Key},
      dataType: 'json',
    }).done(function(data){
     var _status=data.success;
         var _scores=data.score;
     
      if( _status==false || _scores<0.5)
        {
            console.log("Check now, Incorrect");
            $("#submitID").prop('disabled',true);       
     }else{
         $("#submitID").prop('disabled',false);
            console.log("Correct");
    }
      });
    });
    }); 
}
</script>

I tried running through the URL but everytime I receive as below when I enter all the data in the POSTMAN, Please help me in sorting the code.
{
"success": false,
"error-codes": [
"timeout-or-duplicate"
]
}
